# Help me find my Debian Linux IRQ Kernel Panic Trace problem

Tags: linux, debian, network-interface, kernel-panic, wake-on-lan

I have been having kernel panic traces crashing my media server. Nothing is running or installed outside the normal Debian packages and nothing that would have anything to do with the kernel. It runs docker containers related to streaming TV. It runs web servers for local use. It doesn't have heavy bandwidth use. All the errors have something to do with the network connection to my untrained eyes. The server has been running fine for several years now.

```
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Kernel: Linux 4.19.0-10-amd64
Architecture: x86-64

Manufacturer: ASUSTeK Computer INC.
Product Name: M4A79 Deluxe
Version: Rev 1.xx

Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
Version: 1702
Release Date: 06/10/2009
```

The motherboard has an onboard network card.

I have a server environment with no graphical desktop display. Normally there is no screen attached but I have been keeping one attached now that I have been crashing. The screen will only show a blinking login cursor, as normal for this type of setup. When a crash happens the following will take over the screen. I thought I could scroll up and down but this is all I could capture with a camera. I have to use the reset button to restart the server. Nothing in the logs anywhere.

[View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6weA.jpg)

I usually have an SSH terminal open connected to the server, which is local network only. In the terminal the SSH session was kicked off with the following error:

```
kernel:[17313.370419] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
```

I thought it was a Wake on LAN problem. So I made sure it was disabled. I couldn't find it in the BIOS but it was likely called something else so I'll have to look harder if this is indeed what the problem is.

```
sudo ethtool eth0 | grep Wake
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: ug
sudo ethtool -s eth0 wol d
sudo ethtool eth0 | grep Wake
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: d
```

This server is always on, no hibernation or sleep mode enabled. Usually streaming live TV to another PC. It just started behaving this way this week and has crashed 3 times now in the last several days. Is it related to the r8169 network driver? Do I need to use another network card? I don't know anything about these kernel panic traces as this is the first one I have had to deal with.

Thank you for any help you can provide with your expertise.

Comment: Nothing under /var/log?

Comment: Nope, nothing in the log files. Whatever is happening the system isn't able to write any log files. I can see logs from before the crash followed by logs of the restart but nothing in between where the crash logs should be.

Comment: A problem with one of the disk-drives, first suspect: the one housing the /var partition.

Comment: /var is located on a new SSD purchased in July 2019 which is the beginning of life for this server install. No errors were found using `smartctl` and a short self test reported no errors as well. I suppose it could be a SATA cable going bad but it doesn't explain all the network errors `tcp, ip, irq` in the panic trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had trouble finding what you put on imgur, but I'm afraid you're facing a known bug:

[debian-bugs-dist](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1758563.html)

Comment: Thanks. I hate to upgrade the kernel outside stable releases. https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2020-14356 and https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.kernel/search?q=966846 for helpful links to keep an eye on fixes.

Comment: Can anyone advise me on the most stable steps to fix this issue until a proper fix can be found. Do I downgrade the kernel? Upgrade to 5.7 using backports? Try the unstable 4.19.142 fix? Which kernels are unaffected and will work? The server is unstable and useless as is.

Comment: I'd go for the backports, if you can verify they contain the patch.  Do you know what triggers this bug in your case, only now?

Comment: According to CVE-2020-14356 this bug is fixed in 5.7.10-1 and available in buster-backports. I switched to an earlier installed kernel 4.19.0-9 on boot and am awaiting any crashes but from what I have read this bug is not a problem for that kernel. I still haven't been able to figure out what is causing my crashes, others have mentioned docker containers, which I have. I have other machines on 4.19.0-10 and none of them have crashed and none run docker containers.

Comment: Perhaps you could accept my answer?

Comment: I wanted to make sure this was the real reason for the crashes. So far no crash since yesterday morning after changing to an earlier kernel. I thank you again sir for your help.